# How would you rewrite this Apache redirect into a NGINX location?

Tags: nginx

`RewriteRule "^/scorpa/sa/component/(.*)" "{hidden URL}/psp/prd/EMPLOYEE/HRMS/c/$1?languageCd=CFR" [QSA,R]`

It redirects to a proxy. The following do not work

```
location /scorpa/sa/component/(.*) {
      proxy_pass {hidden URL}/psp/prd/EMPLOYEE/HRMS/c/$1?languageCd=CFR;
}
```

It doesn't interpret the location statement and give a 404 on the URL. Other redirect without regex works, just the one with regex do not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer from reddit.

Regular expressions are specified with the preceding
“~*” modifier (for case-insensitive matching), or the
“~” modifier (for case-sensitive matching)

Location docs: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location